# How change return type of method to JSON

Tags: json, methods, output, refactoring, jsonresult

I am using a component in my dot net core web application. the input parameter of the component is `JSON`. So I should change my original method to send its output as `JSON` with minimum changes. Anybody can help me?

```
public IActionResult OnGetEdit(long ceremonyId)
{

    ceremonyGuest = _ceremonyGuestApplication.GetDetail(ceremonyId);
    ViewData["guests"] = ceremonyGuest.AllGuests;

    return Partial("./Edit", ceremonyGuest);
}
```

Comment: What the component indicate, and what is the `input parameter`?

Comment: The component is dropdown list inside telerik grid

Comment: Can you share the view?

Comment: @karney Solved.